# Adding a Large text box to a page

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am building a page where I want to add a HUGE text entry box.  Just like this:

http://unbouncepages.com/real-time-texts/

I have done normal text fields before, but how do I get the box and font size to be massive?

Answer (score 3):

html:

```
<input type='text' id='my-text-box' value="Default text" />
```

css:

```
#my-text-box {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px; /* or larger */
    height: 2em; /* or larger */
    width: 400px; /* or larger */
}
```

Comment: @meagar: I think the question was asking for a single-line text box, despite its wording.

Comment: @meagar, @Paul seems correct, looking at the linked page in the question.

Comment: oops yeah I realized he meant an input mid-answer but forgot update my closing tag

Comment: @Paul @David I meant he was literally mixing them. He had `<input ...</textarea>`.

Comment: @meagar...*aaaaah* that does make more sense *+1* =)

Comment: @Meagar: doh, sorry, with you.

Answer (score 3):

Try these CSS-Settings:

```
#myLargeTextboxId {
  font-size:33px;
  height:33px;
  left:0;
  line-height:33px;
  padding:8px 8px 7px;
  top:0;
  width:224px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply upping the `font-size` should do it, but you probably want some `padding` in there as well. A massive font with no padding would look quite silly.

FireBug is your friend. Use it on everything you have never seen before and learn.

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the element and it shows this:

```
<input name="phone_number" class="text" id="phone_number" style="padding-bottom: 7px; line-height: 33px; padding-left: 8px; width: 224px; padding-right: 8px; height: 33px; font-size: 33px; top: 0px; padding-top: 8px; left: 0px;" type="text"/>
```